# WP Options table contains large amount of random 32 char string

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I have a WordPress/woocommerce store and I am trying to clean things up a bit as it is very sluggish on the backend.

While investigating I found that my wp_options table contains some option_name that are 32char random string. I am not sure whether to delete them or keep them as I am unable to track them down, like from which plugin they are added.

[image]

Comment: Maybe something encrypted. Can be everything I would be careful.

Comment: Do you know what it could be or how could I find from where it has been added to the option table @Mr.Jo

Comment: Not possible. I see nothing that tells me where it comes from.